# ACF Relationship Past Value to Other Post page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

```
 <?php $series = get_field('series', $post->ID);?> this is the original post i want to get

<?php foreach($series as $series):?>

     <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($series->ID);?>"> <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($series->ID, 'thumbnail');?>"></a>
     <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($series->ID);?>"><h3><?php echo $series->post_title;?></h3></a>

            <li>  Release Date: <b> <?php the_field('release_date', $series->ID);?> </b> </li>
            <li>  Native Title: <b>  <?php the_field('native_title', $series->ID);?>  </b> </li>
            <li>  Country: <b>  <?php the_field('country', $series->ID);?> </b> </li>
            <li>  Aired On: <b>  <?php the_field('aired_on', $series->ID);?> </b> </li>
            <li>  Runtime: <b>  <?php the_field('runtime', $series->ID);?> </b> </li>
            <li>  Network: <b>  <?php the_field('network', $series->ID);?> </b> </li> // this is the field i want to get from another post. this is a relationship field.

<pre>  <?php echo print_r($series);?> </pre>
    
<?php endforeach;?>
```

i want to past the value from post to other post currently, im not getting any data from my original post back to current post.. please help.

Comment: What do you get if you `print_r( $series)` ?

Comment: No is not printing

Comment: If you're not inside the loop, then you need to include the post ID in your get_field

Comment: <?php $series = get_field('series', $post->ID);?> im not getting any data the code is updated.

Comment: Already printing here. im getting a lot. what data im looking for? custom post type?

Comment: Replace `$post->ID` with the actual post id you're trying to receive and test that. `$post->ID` is the current post.

Comment: im getting. Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in..

Comment: Can you add the rest of the template?  If $post is not defined, you might try using get_the_ID() - but in any case, it would help if you showed more of your template in the question.

Comment: Solved.!! everything because of the foreach. thanks!!!